# SwiftUI receive custom Event

Tags: swift, swiftui, event-handling, combine

I have an `ObservableObject` that publishes some values using `@Published` property wrappers. This object also holds a timer.

The question is, how can I fire an event as soon as the timer is executed and handle that event in a view in SwiftUI (I'd prefer using something like `onReceive`)?
Using the Combine framework for publishing changing values already, I'd like to implement this event triggering / handling properly. But all that I've read so far about Combine is always about handling value changes. But in my case it's rather a single simple event (without any values).

I know that I could simply use a closure and call that when the timer expires, and I will do that if there's no better, combine-like solution.

This is a conceptual question for a very simple problem so I think it's self explaining without me coming up with a code example?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63239900/12299030?

Comment: thx but no, not at all. This is just using the timer directly in swiftUI. But in my scenario the event should be fired from within the observable object instance I was talking about. The timer was just an example, it could also be some other cause. So in simple words, Im looking for a way to trigger an event within an observed object and catch/handle that event in swiftUI properly.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ‘.onReceive’ subscriber? It’s a SwiftUI + Combine approach.

Comment: exactly, that's why I mentioned it in my question. I would like to use onRecieve to catch the event. But how can I trigger an event from within my observed object? That is the question.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `Bool` property that is triggered by the timer, then reset in onReceive? (or incrementing an Int?) It feels hack-y, but might work?

Comment: @John Nimis IThank you for your ideas!  tried that using the onChange(of: ..) modifier. But as you said it's very hacky and not very suitable if the event should be able to be triggered more than once. because how should that bool bee invalidated? Invalidating would also trogger onChange, also it cannot be invalidated straight away because then the event wouldn't trigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way SwiftUI works with Combine is via `.onReceive`, which expects a publisher. An object can expose a publisher - whether `Timer` or something else - as a property.

Combine publishers work by emitting values, and if you just need to signal that an event has happened, you can emit `()` aka `Void` values.

This object, by the way, need not be an `ObservableObject`, but it could be.

```
class Foo: ObservableObject {
   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
                    .autoconnect()
                    .map { _ in } // map to Void
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher() // optional, but a good practice
}
```

Now, you can use `.onReceive` to subscribe to the `timer` event:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var foo = Foo()
   @State var int: Int = 0
   var body: some View {
       Text("\(int)")
          .onReceive(timer) {
              self.int += 1
          }
   }
}
```

---

Of course, you're not restricted to a TimerPublisher. For example, if some random event happens, you can use a `PassthroughSubject` to publish a value:

```
class Foo {
   let eventA: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>
   private let subject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

   init() {
      
      eventA = subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
      
      let delay = Double.random(in: 10...100)
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) { [weak self] in
          // something random happened, notify
          self?.subject.send()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That second part is exactly the solution I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you could dedicate a specific thread to that Object? And then listen and fire things on that Queue specifically. I've never done this before but it seems like the right sort of idea.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ios-concurrency/

Comment: hey, thx for the idea and the links provided! I will definately look into that but at a first glance having to switch onto a different thread seems a bit overcomplicated to me. I mean, fireing and receiving event's is such a simple task and the combine framework seems to be the ideal framework for such so I would really wonder if it does not support this in some effortless (but somehow unmentioned:D) way..